# Bootstrap 2.3.2 popover style not working on IE 11 (and older)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm creating a simple bootstrap 2.3.2 popover on my page and it works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox, but when it comes to IE, the popover style is not showed correctly:

[IE screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAUGo.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
<a href="#" id="pop" rel="popover">(ver detalle) </a>

<div id="popoverContent" class="hide">
  <p>110001</p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    $("#pop").popover({
        content: $('#popoverContent').html(), 
        title: "Detalle"
    });
```

Comment: is java script enabled in the browser?

Comment: javascript is enabled

Comment: I already solved it but i cannot post the answer till 6 hours later because of my reputation so i'll write it here.
The problem was that internet explorer was running the page in compatibility view mode wich was enabled by default for intranet websites. I solved it by pressing Alt key to show the menu bar and going to Tools>Compatibility View Settings, and unchecking the "Display intranet sites in compatibility view."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that internet explorer was running the page in compatibility view mode wich was enabled by default for intranet websites. I solved it by pressing Alt key to show the menu bar and going to Tools>Compatibility View Settings, and unchecking the "Display intranet sites in compatibility view."

Answer (score 0):

You had a pretty simple fix, but if you are using a popover and filling in the title you should be sure that you are not emptying it back out.  I know we are using bs tooltips, and I used the popover for some d3.js stuff.  Well in Chrome I was getting a popover and tooltip, so I emptied the attribute "title" out.  That caused IE to freeze on hover.  So I had to check if it was IE and not remove the title.  It is a mess, but if someone else is having this issue you are not going to see this one coming.